# Could I call the value of object directly in python? So in this case I'm not getting the object instance?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 
p1=Point([1,2,99])

I got the value when I write:
p1.coordinate

> > [1, 2, 99]

but when I write:
p1
I got:
<**main**.Point at 0x7ff3f5f9b908>

is there a way so when I write:
p1
the result is direct(without need type object.coordinate):

> > [1, 2, 99]

## A minimalist Point class (represents an x,y coordinate)

class Point:
    def **getitem**(self,index):
        return self.coordinate[index]

```
def __setitem__(self,index,value):
    self.coordinate[index] = value

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.coordinate)


def checkLens(cls,p):
    print(len(p))
    if (len(p))<1:
        raise Exception("Zero-dimensional point are illegal")

# __init__ function is the constructor
def __init__(self,coordinate=[0,0]):
    self.coordinate=coordinate
    self.checkLens(self)

#move the point by x,y    
def moveBy(self,p=[0,0]):
    self.checkLens(p)
    self.coordinate+=p


#move the point to x,y
def moveTo(self,p=[0,0]):
    self.checkLens(p)
    self.coordinate=p

#calculate Hamming distance between two points   
def distanceTo(self, p2):
    return abs(self.coordinate-p2.coordinate)

# __str__ generates string representation of objects   
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.coordinate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `__repr__` special method is for:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.coordinate)
```

Please research a bit more about the best practices when it comes to defining a `__repr__` method. What I showed you was merely for demonstration.